# Should I use a timestamp field in mysql for timezones or other?

Tags: php, mysql, time

MY previous site used DATETIME fileds in MySQL to store all dates/times.  On my new site I am adding in timezone capability so I am wanting to store all submitted times at UTC timestamp, I am a little confused now though after reading another post on SO, I read that the timestamp is updated everytime you update the record, if that is the case then should I be storing my UTC timestamp into a text filed or what?

I was planning to store the UTC value with this below, am I wrong, please help

```
$now = gmdate('U', time());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that the timestamp is updated
>   everytime you update the record

Just some info on timestamps:

- For one `TIMESTAMP` column in a table,
  you can assign the current timestamp
  as the default value and the
  auto-update value. It is possible to
  have the current timestamp be the
  default value for initializing the
  column, for the auto-update value, or
  both. It is not possible to have the
  current timestamp be the default
  value for one column and the
  auto-update value for another column.
- Any single `TIMESTAMP` column in a
  table can be used as the one that is
  initialized to the current date and
  time, or updated automatically. This
  need not be the first `TIMESTAMP`
  column.
- If a `DEFAULT` value is specified for
  the first `TIMESTAMP` column in a
  table, it is not ignored. The default
  can be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or a
  constant date and time value.
- To specify automatic default or
  updating for a `TIMESTAMP` column other
  than the first one, you must suppress
  the automatic initialization and
  update behaviors for the first
  `TIMESTAMP` column by explicitly
  assigning it a constant `DEFAULT` value
  (for example, `DEFAULT 0` or `DEFAULT
  '2003-01-01 00:00:00'`). Then, for the
  other `TIMESTAMP` column, the rules are
  the same as for the first `TIMESTAMP`
  column, except that if you omit both
  of the `DEFAULT` and `ON UPDATE` clauses,
  no automatic initialization or
  updating occurs.

Answer (score 1):

`ADD COLUMN name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0` is your friend.  Without `DEFAULT some_constant_value`, MySQL will automatically update the column every time the row is updated (ref. [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: ... 10.3.1.1 TIMESTAMP Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html))